# SQL Commands in VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

```
Sub querystringforbiz_pro()

' Defining the object type
Dim data As ADODB.Connection
Dim datarecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim header As ADODB.Field


Workbooks("account").Activate
' initiating the new instance of the cinnection
Set data = New ADODB.Connection
Set datarecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

' definig the connection string
 data.ConnectionString = "xxxxxxx"

 biz = Sheets("MID").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).value

' Activating the connection
data.Open

' Sepcification for the recordset
bizquery = "Select m.id, m.company_name, m.url From payu.merchant as m where m.id in (" & biz & ")"

With datarecordset
    .ActiveConnection = data
    .Source = bizquery
    .LockType = adLockReadOnly
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .Open
End With

Workbooks("UpdatingthenewMIDs").Activate
Worksheets.Add

Range("A1").Activate

For Each header In datarecordset.Fields
    ActiveCell.Value = header.Name
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Next header


Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset datarecordset

datarecordset.Close
data.Close
```

SO I want to pass the entire list of IDs in one go and find the names against those IDs.

When i am copying the data in varibale "BIZ" and using it in the query, it is throwing the Error "Type Mismatch"

Please suggest how can I pass the entire list of ID in a single go in the query (dont want to use for loop)

Comment: 'biz' will be an array taking it like that.  You need to join the array

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
...
biz = Sheets("MID").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Value
Dim ValueList As String
ValueList = ""
For Each cell In biz
    If ValueList <> "" Then
        ValueList = ValueList & ", "
    End If
    ValueList = ValueList & cell
Next cell
...
bizquery = "Select m.id, m.company_name, m.url From payu.merchant as m where m.id in (" & ValueList & ")"
...
```

Comment: biz = Sheets("MID").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Value - this statement is giving an error - "Object Required"..!

Comment: Thanks Sam. the following line worked : biz = Sheets("MID").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)) - (I have removed the Value property )